# Imbalanced learning - under sampling vs. over sampling vs. weight based classifiers

Tags: unbalanced-classes

Does anyone know what is the difference (theoretically speaking) between

- under sampling
- over sampling
- weight based classifiers

when dealing with highly imbalanced datasets (1:1000, 1:10000)?

When is it recommended to use each one?

Is there a theoretic justification for any of these methods? or do they just "work pretty good"?

Comment: You might find this paper by He and Garcia (2009) to be helpful: http://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/he/PDFfiles/ImbalancedLearning.pdf